# How to change QPushButton icon using stylesheets?

Tags: qt, icons, qtstylesheets, qpushbutton

Is it possible to set and change the icon on a QPushButton using stylesheets?

I need this for a Windows-based white-label Qt4.5 application that customers stylize using stylesheets.

Answer (score 8):

You can add the icon by changing the `QAbstractButton-property`. Simply use:

```
QAbstractButton {
    qproperty-icon: theme_url("/button_action/add");
}
```

The type-selector `QAbstractButton` allows you to set the style for the selected object **and** all **its subclasses**.

Since `QPushButton` extends `QAbstractButton` this does the trick. (Of course, you could also use `QPushButton` type-selector instead).

For more information on how to use selectors I found [this section in the docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) quite helpful.

If you want to learn more about the available button-properties, refer to the Qt-Documentation [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html).

PS. If you want to toggle the icon whenever the button is pressed use:

```
qproperty-icon: url(":/Icons/before_click.png") off,
                url(":/Icons/after_click.png") on ;
```

Comment: Does anybody know where the on/off syntax is documented? I've never seen this before.

Answer (score 0):

Yup.

```
border-image: url(/url/to/image);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. This appears to set the background of my QPushButton to the image rather than the QPushButton's icon. Any ideas what I've done wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Huh, I thought that set the icon, with `background-image:` setting the background. I'd have to play with it, apparently my memory is not what it used to be.

Comment: It looks like you have to style the icon size, the alignment, and the text alignment so everything lays out correctly. I don't have time to mess with it right now, but everything I read via a couple google searches says that `border-image:` is the icon in regard to the stylesheet.

Comment: You can use `border-image` to change the appearance of the button, e. g. with a dotted border or ornaments. It has nothing to do with the icon.

Answer (score -2):

You can use:

`image: url(/url/to/image);`

See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#image-prop and http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-customizing.html#box-model.

Comment: Nope, this adds a new icon to the center of the button.