# How to set the QToolButton's icons using style sheet?

Tags: c++, qt4, stylesheet

I would like to set a QToolButton's icons using style sheets, like this :

```
#include <QToolButton>
#include <QApplication>

QString FormStyleSheetString( const QString & name )
{
  const QString thisItemStyle( "QToolButton:enabled { image: url(" + name + "_normal.png); }  "
                             "QToolButton:pressed { image: url(" + name + "_pressed.png); }  "
                             "QToolButton:disabled { image: url(" + name + "_disabled.png); }  "
                           );

  return thisItemStyle;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    QApplication qapp(argc,argv);

    QToolButton button;
    button.setStyleSheet( FormStyleSheetString( "button" ) );
    button.setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextUnderIcon);
    button.setIconSize(QSize(200,200));
    button.setText("some thing..." );
    button.show();

    return qapp.exec();
}
```

I compiled it like this :

```
g++ -O3 -std=c++0x -Wall -Wextra -pedantic test.cpp -lQtCore -lQtGui -I/usr/include/Qt/ -I/usr/include/QtCore/ -I/usr/include/QtGui/
```

Unfortunately, the above doesn't work (the icon is not shown).

If I use [setIcon](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qabstractbutton.html#icon-prop), then the icon is shown properly.

So, what am I doing wrong? How to set the button's icon using style sheet?

The images I used are :
[image: button_normal.png]
[image: button_pressed.png]
[image: button_disabled.png]

PS Take a note that I asked similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382421/how-to-set-a-qt-buttons-icons-using-stylesheet/8382759#8382759), but the answer doesn't work once the text is set (the icon is all squished, and the text is not below the icon).

EDIT 1:
I also tried this function (as Kamil Klimek suggested) :

```
QString FormStyleSheetString( const QString & name )
{
  const QString thisItemStyle( "QToolButton { qproperty-icon: url(" + name + "_normal.png); };  "
                               "QToolButton:pressed { qproperty-icon: url(" + name + "_pressed.png); };  "
                               "QToolButton:hover { qproperty-icon: url(" + name + "_disabled.png); };  "
                               );

  return thisItemStyle;
}
```

but it also didn't work. Pressing the button, or hovering, doesn't change the icon.

Comment: you set an image not an icon. try qproperty-icon: url()

Comment: @KamilKlimek I tried that, but it didn't work. It would set the normal image, but not pressed and hover. I think it is because of this bug : https://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-2982?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin:activity-stream-issue-tab

Comment: then you have to set it as image or background !BUT! you will have to adjust size with CSS.

Comment: @KamilKlimek If I set it as background, then the text is centred. Setting it as an image doesn't work (the image is not shown).

Comment: Could you try with "background-image" instead of "image".

Comment: @milyaaf I tried, but it didn't work. It looks like the style sheets implementation in QT is still not mature enough. A workaround is to set the sizes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Later that day I managed to somehow solve the problem, but forgot to post the solution :

```
QString FormStyleSheetString( const QString & name )
{
  const QString thisItemStyle(
  "QToolButton {\n"
                "   border: none;\n"
                "   background: url(" + name + "_normal.png) top center no-repeat;\n"
                "   padding-top: 200px;\n"
                "   width: 200px;\n"
                "   font: bold 14px;\n"
                "   color: red;\n"
                "}\n"
                "QToolButton:hover {\n"
                "   background: url("+name+"_hover.png) top center no-repeat;\n"
                "   color: blue;\n"
                "}\n"
                "QToolButton:pressed {\n"
                "   background: url("+name+"_pressed.png) top center no-repeat;\n"
                "   color: gray;\n}" );

  return thisItemStyle;
}
```

It wasn't enough just to set the background. It also needed the size fixed.